# Show an Alertdialog on Checkbox click

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a checkbox that can be either checked or unchecked. When the checkbox is checked and the user clicks it I want to display an AlertDialog without unchecking the checkbox (because when you click on the checkbox it becomes unchecked as it just follows the status change). In the AlertDialog I want to ask the user if they really want to uncheck it, and only then set the checkbox unchecked.

I am not providing any more code as it is not necessary. I need guidance.

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {

        } else {

        }
    }
});
```

Please do not add any solutions that adds the dialog in the `if (isChecked) {}` block, as per the documentation:

> A button with two states, checked and unchecked. When the button is
>   pressed or clicked, the state changes automatically.

This means the listener runs AFTER the checkbox's state as changed so it's too late to display a dialog then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a custom checkbox and override it's toggle method to do whatever you want with the states. Here is some basic code to exemplify the functionality:

In xml, declare your custom view as follows(change your package name):

```
<com.example.mike.myapplication.CustomCheckBox
    android:id="@+id/my_checkbox"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Then initialize it in your Activity/fragment:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    cb = (CustomCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.my_checkbox);
    // You should ALWAYS add this listener!!!!
    cb.addListener(new CustomCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onConfirmCheckDisable() {
            buildDialog();
        }
    });
}

private void buildDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Confirm")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to uncheck this entry?")
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                   cb.setChecked(false);
              }
        })
       .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
               // do nothing
        }
       })
       .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
       .show();
}
```

This is your Custom checkbox class:

```
public class CustomCheckBox extends CheckBox {

    private CustomCheckedChangeListener mListener;

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public CustomCheckBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void addListener(CustomCheckedChangeListener list){
        mListener = list;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggle() {
        if (mListener == null) return;
        if (isChecked()) {
            mListener.onConfirmCheckDisable();
        } else {
            super.toggle();
        }
    }
}
```

And this is your listener:

```
public interface CustomCheckedChangeListener {

    public void onConfirmCheckDisable();
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Hi Mike. This would not work as you show the dialog after the status has been changed to unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (be careful of the context here though, if you are in fragment call getActivity()):

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

       if (isChecked) {
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
          builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to uncheck this ?")
          .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                    buttonView.setChecked(false);
               }
          }).setNegaviteButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id){
                   buttonView.setChecked(true);
                 }
          });
          AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
          alertDialog.show();
       } 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just create an AlertDialog, look

```
cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

        if (isChecked) {
             confirmCheck();
        }
    }
});

private void confirmCheck() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                  .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                  .setTitle("WARNING!")
                  .setMessage("¿Sure u check?")
                  .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which){
                          cb.setChecked(false);
                    }
                  })
                  .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                  .show();
}
```

I hope I have helped you, greetings.